# Adding css on the element directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this menu `directive`, that is basically absolutely positioned menu popping up when the html elements are clicked on the page. On the html page, it is declared like this:

```
<menu></menu>
```

and it works fine. The only problem  I have with this approach is that this new  `menu` html element is also a block element and as such it creates empty space. To fix this, I can add css rule

```
menu {
  position absolute;
}
```

or maybe add a custom class:

```
.menu {
  position absolute;
}

<menu class="menu"></menu>
```

What I don't know, is it in the spirit of Angular to take these approaches or is there a better solution  ?

Answer (score 0):

Apply 0 margin and padding:

```
menu{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```